# Ionic 3 where Ionic saves data?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, mobile, progressive-web-apps

I can't find answer anywhere about ionic data saving. For example :

If I use lazy loading - where does unloaded modules stay (RAM or Main storage) or if I use service worker - where all assets are saved ?

**It's important for me because if there are 100 images - whose weight about 100mbs, where those 100mbs goes if app is closed?**

Answer (score 0):

If you're talking about a PWA.  It would strongly suggest you rethink about caching 100 (100MB) images with service worker.   Not only will that not work , it is not a good experience for your users.

To answer your question, it does attempt to save to localstorage, which has its limits by browser and database.

Comment: I am talking about Ionic Storage - mobile apps native plugin. Is it the same ?

Comment: The Native plugin is for devices only.   And it is just a wrapper for actual native storage like sqlite.   When it is access, it stores it in RAM.  So 100MB images will just have a very hard struggle to render no matter what you do.